# Site breaking when I call a custom module up on app.php file

Tags: craft3, php

My Craft CMS version 3 site is breaking when I boostrap a custom module up on app.php file.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php

use craft\helpers\App;

return [
    'id' => App::env('APP_ID') ?: 'CraftCMS',
    'modules' => [
        'my-module' => \modules\Module::class,
        'fa-forms' => \faforms\Module::class
    ],
    'aliases' => [
        '@subdomain' => 'http://subdomain.localhost',
    ], 
    //'bootstrap' => ['fa-forms'],
    //'bootstrap' => ['my-module'],
    'components' => [
        'queue' => [
            'ttr' => 3600,
        ],
    ],
];
```

If I uncomment the bootstrap for the fa-forms module I get a server error that I cannot trace because it prevents the debug toolbar from loading.

Has anyone had a similar issue with bootstrap breaking their site?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the actual error is, it's hard to help you out. Could you try and find the error in the error log, probably located at `storage/logs/web.log`? Error and stack trace should be in there.

Another thing you could do is open a terminal, go to the root folder of your Craft installation and run `tail -f storage/logs/web.log`. This will show additions to the log as they occur. After that, reload the page that throws the error and see what error appears in your terminal window.

Comment: Thanks Paul - that is some very useful information, I really appreciate it!